# Excel apply conditional formatting on the basis of a cell outside range

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a cell range in excel let's say `B6:H40` .

I want to apply a `conditional formatting` on this range such that the data type of cells should be changed to `percentage`  on the condition that : if the cell A1 has Text "True" in it.

How do I apply conditional formatting for such case?

Answer (score 2):

Select `B6:H40`, pull up the conditional formatting dialog and insert the formula:

```
=$A$1="True"
```

Then use the percentage format and click OK. That should do it.